# Can't combine alias with fastcgi_cache in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

This works:

```
location ~ ^/special/(.+\.php)$ {
  alias /var/special/$1;
  try_files "" =404;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # php-fpm socket
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
location ~ ^/special/(.+\.php)$ {
  alias /var/special/$1;
  try_files "" =404;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # php-fpm socket
  fastcgi_cache mycache;
}
```

If I try to go to the URL "/special/index.php" I get a "File not found." text in the browser, which I assume comes from php-fpm or PHP. And I get this error in the Nginx log:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown", client: 202.179.27.65, server: myserver.org, request: "GET /special/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "myserver.org"
```

Any idea why adding fastcgi_cache breaks this?

Note that fastcgi_cache works fine when I use a location that **doesn't** use an alias.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days (!) of fiddling with it, this variation **seems** to work:

```
location ~ ^/special(/.+\.php)$ {
  root /var/special;
  try_files "" =404;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # php-fpm socket
  fastcgi_cache mycache;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $1;
}
```

What seemed to make the difference is 1) using "root", which seems to be needed by the fastcgi_cache, and 2) explicitly setting SCRIPT_FILENAME and SCRIPT_NAME, because otherwise the "root" wouldn't work (even without fastcgi_cache).